# How to explain this Akka Streams graph from official doc?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a couple of questions for this sample code hosted officially [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html#tab0):

```
val topHeadSink = Sink.head[Int]
val bottomHeadSink = Sink.head[Int]
val sharedDoubler = Flow[Int].map(_ * 2)

RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
  (topHS, bottomHS) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  Source.single(1) ~> broadcast.in

  broadcast.out(0) ~> sharedDoubler ~> topHS.in
  broadcast.out(1) ~> sharedDoubler ~> bottomHS.in
  ClosedShape
})
```

1. When do you pass in a graph through `create`?

Why are `topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink` passed in through create, but `sharedDoubler` is not? What is the difference between them?

2. When do you need `builder.add`?

Can I create a broadcast outside the graph without `builder.add`? If I add a couple of flows inside the graph, should I add the flows via `builder.add` as well? It is very confusing that sometimes we need `builder.add` and sometimes we do not.

**Update**

I feel this is still confusing:

*The difference between these approaches is that importing using `builder.add(...)` ignores the materialized value of the imported graph, while importing via the factory method allows its inclusion.*

`topHS, bottomHS` are imported from `create`, so they will keep their materialized value. What if I do `builder.add(topHS)`?

And how do you explain `sharedDoubler`: does it have a materialized value or not? What if I use `builder.add` with it?

3. What does this mean, the `((_,_))` of `GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((_, _))`?

It looks like boilerplate we just need, but I am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. When do you pass in a graph through create?

When you want to obtain the materialized value of the graph that you pass to the `create` factory method. The type of the `RunnableGraph` in your question is `RunnableGraph[(Future[Int], Future[Int])]`, meaning that the materialized value of the graph is `(Future[Int], Future[Int])`:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(...).run() // (Future[Int], Future[Int])
val topHeadSinkResult    = g._1 // Future[Int]
val bottomHeadSinkResult = g._2 // Future[Int]
```

Now consider the following variant, which defines the sinks "inside" the graph and discards the materialized value:

```
val g2 = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val topHeadSink = Sink.head[Int]
  val bottomHeadSink = Sink.head[Int]
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))

  Source.single(1) ~> broadcast.in
  broadcast.out(0) ~> sharedDoubler ~> topHeadSink
  broadcast.out(1) ~> sharedDoubler ~> bottomHeadSink
  ClosedShape
}).run() // NotUsed
```

The value of `g2` is `NotUsed`.

> 2. When do you need builder.add?

All of the components of a graph must be added to the builder, but there are variants of the [`~>`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.9/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Graph.scala#L1303) operator that add the most commonly used components--such as `Source` and `Flow`--to the builder under the covers. However, *junction* operations that perform a fan-in (such as `Merge`) or a fan-out (such as `Broadcast`) must be explicitly passed to `builder.add` if you're using the Graph DSL.

Note that for simple graphs, you can use junctions without having to use the Graph DSL. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html#combining-sources-and-sinks-with-simplified-api):

```
val sendRmotely = Sink.actorRef(actorRef, "Done")
val localProcessing = Sink.foreach[Int](_ => /* do something usefull */ ())

val sink = Sink.combine(sendRmotely, localProcessing)(Broadcast[Int](_))

Source(List(0, 1, 2)).runWith(sink)
```

> 3. What does this mean? the `((_,_))` of `GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((_, _))`?

It's a curried parameter that specifies which materialized value(s) you want to retain. Using `((_, _))` here is the same as:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((t, b) => (t, b)) {
  implicit builder => (topHS, bottomHS) =>
  ...
}).run() // (Future[Int], Future[Int])
```

In other words, `((_, _))` in this context is shorthand for `((t, b) => (t, b))`, which preserves the respective materialized values of the two sinks that are passed in. If, for example, you want to keep only the materialized value of `topHeadSink`, you could change the call to the following:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((t, _) => t) {
  implicit builder => (topHS, bottomHS) =>
  ...
}).run() // Future[Int]
```

Comment: Thanks @chunjef! The answer is great. I have one more question for `sharedDoubler`, it does not go through `create` and neither created inside the graph, what happens to its materialized value? Why we have two ways to pass graph into another? one through `create`, one does not?

Or flow does not retain materialized value? so you only need to add source, sink through `create`?